# How to combine the similar rxjs streams?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following RXJS streams:

```
    this.widthBorder$.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe((value) => {
        this.registryBoundaries.setAttribute('stroke-width', `${value || 0}`);
    });

    this.widthBorderColor$.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe((value) => {
        this.registryBoundaries.setAttribute('stroke', `${value || 0}`);
    });

    this.drawContour$.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe((value) => {
        this.registryBoundaries.style.display = value ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
```

As you can see there are a duplicates of code like `skip(1)` also there methods are the similar?

I skip first value because all streams are `BehaviorSubject`.

How to optimize it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you should use [`Subject`](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject) instead of [`BehaviorSubject`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) for this case. Subject will emit no initial value upon subscription and this will save you the need to use the `skip` operator.

For reading from multiple observables, there is no magic solution. You may use a thing like [`zip`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/zip) so you have an array of emitted values of the observables (but you will have to pipe each observable with startWith(null) so they emit a value, since zip will only emit once all observables have emitted). You may also use [`merge`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/merge) to simply fuse all observables into a single observable, but you won't be able to tell which observable has emitted the received value unless you add some sort of tag.

I think your implementation is fine once you switch from `BehaviorSubject` to `Subject` and remove all the skip operators. If you had ten more subscriptions like this, I would suggest creating the observables programatically, but for three subscriptions nothing will save you much lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

just use `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject`

**BehaviourSubject**

> **BehaviourSubject will return the initial value or the current value on Subscription**

**Subject**

> **Subject does not return the current value on Subscription. It triggers only on .next(value) call and return/output the value**

```
public widthBorder$ = new Subject();
public widthBorderColor$ = new Subject();
public rawContour$ = new Subject();

this.widthBorder$.subscribe(v => this.setAttribute('stroke', `${v || 0}`));

this.widthBorderColor$.subscribe(v => this.setAttribute('stroke-width', `${v || 0}`));

this.drawContour$.subscribe((value) => {
    this.registryBoundaries.style.display = value ? 'block' : 'none';
});

public setAttribute(attr: string, value: string): void {
    this.registryBoundaries.setAttribute(attr, value);
}
```